# Select text in input box on user select or focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying that when I change into drop-down, the input box should be focused and value of input box should be selected.
I used

```
$("#text_qty").focus(function () {
    this.select();
});
```

but it is not working .

This is my input box

```
<input type="number" name="text_qty" id="text_qty"  value="0" onKeyUp="cal_price()" onChange="cal_price()" min="0"/>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#text_qty").focus(function () { $(this).select(); });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$("#select").change(function () {
        $("#text_qty").focus();
        $("#text_qty").val($("select option:selected").val());
    })
```

Comment: #select is the id of '<select>' tag